How can I assign households to coordinates in a social space consistent with pairwise distance measures?
How can I assign households to coordinates in a social space consistent with pairwise distance measures?
I have a question which is somewhat ill-defined, about creating an interesting and useful measure of social distance.
In the past this has been done, e.g., to squash socioeconomic status into a single dimension. However, in that case, although they wanted a metric that was internally consistent, I think they were just as interested in creating one that corresponded with their intuitions, whereas I want to be led by the data, not to lead it. This is a kind of question many people have faced, and I think a clearer definition of the problem and a technical solution to it go hand in hand.
I have a lot of vectors of  measurements of characteristics of people. I also have a meaningful but noisy pairwise distance measure based on similarity. I could assign each characteristic to a dimension and then locate these points, but for my purposes these locations would not be useful. Only the distances between the points matters. For purposes of this question, assume I have distance measurements mean something, or just let me worry about constructing distance.
I have measurements on about 180 characteristics. Some are continuous, with meaningful differences and ratios. Others are categorical, which is why I hesitate to use PCA. I am currently leaning toward a Jaccard measure to convert categorical differences into a measure of difference and hence distance. I am looking for a way to reduce those dimensions consistent with the distance measurements. Once I have flattened the data as much as it will tolerate, I'll be looking for interesting features, relationships and shapes with a methodology that lets the data speak without imposing a linear model on it. For instance there are several topological data analysis methods like persistent homology that I want to try.
Most of the statistical analyses I've done over the years have been econometric or econometric-derived, and has consisted almost entirely of variants on linear regression. In the past when I have talked about nonlinear models, I have usually meant models that were linear in logs, or including quadratic terms and interaction terms, or the like. Stepping out of that territory feels exciting and a little scary. I would not have guessed that there are practical techniques to find shapes in the data without being pretty specific about what sort of shapes you allow.
It world be convenient if I could assign the points locations consistent with the my distance measures. And for purposes of insight, and data visualization, I would like to use as few dimensions as possible. How -- by what criteria -- do i determine how many dimensions I need?
On one hand, the less error I tolerate, the more dimensions are required. When some points are further apart from each of two other points than those other points are from each other, popping the bigger distance out into another dimension can avoid a violation of the triangle inequality. If there are a lot of big violations of the triangle inequality, then a spatial location  is probably not a useful analogy for social position or social distance. Knowing if it is or is not is itself interesting. But because my distance measures are noisy, it makes sense to allow some minor adjustment in distances if it means I can flatten my data into fewer dimensions.
Once I have a number of dimensions, I want to find a set of coordinates for  for each point-pair consistent with that number of dimensions and my distance measures. I do not care about rotations or translations of the point cloud, and am happy to use whatever is convenient. Can anyone suggest a technique by which I can do this?

Your query refers to households, your data refers to people. It would help if you provided more information about the data. A few methods come to mind which are intended for mixtures of data. Correspondence analysis is PCA for such mixtures, returning a low dimensional set of projections. Latent class analysis is another, best implemented with a very flexible, inexpensive software Latent Gold. Their website has a ton of papers describing it and it's well covered on CV. https://www.statisticalinnovations.com/latent-gold-6-0/
